# Updating one observable property of knockout after ajax get

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am trying to implement a filtering in my knockout application using a AJAX get and i want to update only one of the many observables in the viewmodel.
This is my viewmodel here in JS

```
function containerViewModel() {
mainViewModel = this;
mainViewModel.isBusy = ko.observable(false);
mainViewModel.errorMessage = ko.observable("");
mainViewModel.containerModel = ko.observable(
    {
        HomeSettings: ko.observable(),
        Employee: ko.observable(),
        Class: ko.observable(),
        Degree: ko.observable(),
        Specialization: ko.observable(),
        }
        );

    GET_AllContainer(mainViewModel);
}
```

Each of these observables are shown in different tabs and each tab has filter buttons. When i click the filter button from any tab, i fetch the data using ajax call. But the problem is am getting the whole data and binding to the viewmodel as this

```
function GET_FilteredContainer(mainView, filterText, productID, FilterID) {
mainViewModel.isBusy(true);
$.ajax({
    url: hostApi + api_GetAllContainer,
    contentType: "json",
    data: { FilterLinkIds: filterText, ProductID: productID },
    success: function (result) {
        mainView.containerModel(result);            
        SetFilterButtonCSS(productID, FilterID);
        ProductReportsNotFound(result);
        mainViewModel.isBusy(false);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        mainViewModel.errorMessage(result);
        mainViewModel.isBusy(false);
    }
});
}
```

But this means it will clear the filter of other tabs. So is there any way i can update only the required observable only

Can anyone help me.

Comment: you mean something like this in ajax success `mainView.containerModel().Specialization('M.S')` .

Comment: Yes. Each observable item has a list and all. Like the filtering collection of Specializations resides inside it and like that there are two list and some other properties for Specialization,Class,Degree and so on. So when i click a filter in specialization, i will get the updated list of items that belong to Specialization plus filter list and other properties and i need to update only the Specialization observable in viewmodel.

Comment: you need to pass which observable you want to update((i.e Employee, Degree) on `click` as your are using each observable in each tab you should have its reference to pass & conditionally update in ajax success .

Comment: I will be able to identify the which object of containerModel  i am updaing , but how can i write it in script. In success of ajax shall use this 
    mainView.containerModel.ERPData=result.ERPData ??? Will it update the binding in view?

Comment: yes but something like this `mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData)` .

Comment: check sample here 2-way binding is intact here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26146/ . hope that helps

Comment: Will that make other object of that observable null?

Comment: I got this error while trying ur code.
Uncaught TypeError: mainview.containerModel(...).ERPData is not a function.

Comment: it doesn't make other observable's null as you are not re-initializing it . if it says its not a function means your ERPData is not a observable just in case you declared it observable somewhere `it being` observable broken .

Comment: But i have a doubt, containerModel is an observable and inside it we are created ERPData as observable. What does that mean?

Comment: I gave something like this mainView.containerModel().ERPData = result.ERPData;, but its not reflecting in the view.

Comment: it means observable inside observable i.e child array inside parent array . @arjun i mentioned in one of my above comment you should do like this `mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData)` not `=` .

Comment: Hi,
mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData) is throwing an error as i mentioned above.ERPData is not a function. It will be good if you can post some code as answer and i can implement and comment

Comment: if error states its not a function means you haven't declared it as observable or somewhere 2-way binding is lost (it commonly happens if you use `=` notation somewhere before for assigning data) . hope you can track it down .

Comment: I will look @ it and will get back to you. Thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: Hi super cool,I have a doubt regarding updating only specified observables under containerModel.
     `mainViewModel.containerModel = ko.observable(
        {
            HomeSettings: ko.observable(),
        }
        );`
This means an observable containerModel,has another observable HomeSettings. You provided a code mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData). But this means its treating the ERPData as a function rt? We are trying to update a child observable of parent containerModel ?

Comment: What if i gave like this `      mainView.containerModel({ ERPData: result.ERPData });`. It will update only the ERPData only rt?

Comment: `mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData)` will update specific observable i.e ERPData in this context which is inside containerModel which works fine . the way you mentioned `({//})` is not correct n not a standard one .

Comment: Sorry for the repeated questions. I saw the example you shared. The ERP Data is a c# modelview class which has two lists inside it and it confuses me that writing , result.ERPData is an object right? So when we write code as u mentioned above, it means ERPData of containerModel acts a function which is not. So that will throw an error saying its not a function rt?

Comment: hum i feel you misunderstood the concept of serverModel and viewModel . if you declare ERPData as observable inside ContainerModel it means its a function which is (observable itself a function you should read it via `()` and assign it `(youValue)`) and you assign object coming from server i.e result.ERPData . if you getting error while doing this `mainView.containerModel().ERPData(result.ERPData)` may be ERPData is not declared as observable else you saying you getting 2 Lists from server so that decalre it as observableArray instead as observable n try . show JSON Data passing from server

Comment: Hi, this is the controller method 
`[Route("api/ProductsApi/GetAllContainer")]
        public ContainerViewModel GetAllContainer()
        {
            return new ContainerViewModel();
        }
From the code i mentioned in the question you can see that ERPData is an observable under containerModel.  In the success of the first method i am using this ` mainView.containerModel(result);`

Comment: ERPData: Object
BodyText: "BodyText"
Filters: Array[7]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
FooterText: "FooterText"
HeaderText: "HeaderText"
IconImage: "img/assad.jpg"
IconText: ""
IsVisible: true
Navigations: Array[37]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object

PageTitle: "Title"
ProductGUId: "2"
ProductId: 1
HomeSettings: Object
IDEAData: Object
KPIData: Object
QlikViewData: Object
ScreeningData: Object
TopNavigations: null
iJETData: Object

Comment: what if i set each as separate observables not under containermodel and do something like this
`function containerViewModel() {
    mainViewModel = this;
    mainViewModel.ERPData = ko.observable();
    mainViewModel.setAllData = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: hostApi + "ProductsApi/GetAllContainer",
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                mainViewModel.ERPData(result.ERPData);
            },      
        });
    };
    mainViewModel.setAllData();
}`

Comment: and in the html i can write like this
` <section class="sectionBlock noPadding" id="ERP_Screen" data-bind="visible: ERPData.IsVisible">
            <div id="sideBar-Left-ERP" class="col-md-3 sideBar-Left" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(' + ERPData.IconImage + ')' }">
                <div class="sideBar-transperant sideBar-transperant-erp">
                    <div class="col-md-12 sideRightContent" data-bind="template: { name: 'Report-Message', data: ERPData }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </section>` But its not working :(

Comment: can you please see this JSFiddle i created https://jsfiddle.net/3bzg7r9g/4/

Comment: as far i see you are doing things pretty wrong . modified your fiddle to work http://jsfiddle.net/3bzg7r9g/6/ .

Comment: biggest mistake in you code is `mainView.containerModel(result)` this line . you are replacing everything with some non observable object data and you expecting when you assign like that observables automatically fill up but it doesn't & wont  .

Comment: Hi, i forgot to update the fiddle with the index, sorry. As per the code in my question, containerModel(which is an observable) has ERPData another observable. So what I have understood so far is observable acts a functioon, if we are using it without a parameter its get, if it has parameter then its set. So what i change the structure and rather than using containerModel as a parent observable, i keep ERPData and three other more as independent observables. I was able to set the data, but when i bind the data to html page i should write say ERPData().ID,ERPData().Name rt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are quite a few mistakes in code

`mainView.containerModel(result)` is a  **Major one** which you can't do because it will replace entire observable content as in you case it replaces observable's you have in your declaration(`containerModel`) rather filling those (as you may thought it would ) .

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.containerModel = ko.observable({
        HomeSettings: ko.observable(),
        Employee: ko.observable(),
        Class: ko.observable(),
        Degree: ko.observable(),
        Specialization: ko.observable(),
    });

     var result = [{'HomeSettings':[1,2,3,4],'Employee':1}]
        console.log("Object you getting at ajax call success")
        console.log(result) //sample check

    console.log("correct way1 o/p")
    self.containerModel().HomeSettings(result[0].HomeSettings);
    self.containerModel().Employee(result[0].Employee);
    //like that for everything i.e see console everything is a function 
    console.log(self.containerModel())                                
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26261/)**

**PS:** Advisable way would be like have a function written outside and declare you observable's in it . later you can use `.map` or `mapping plugin` to do your assigning in a neat flexible way to containerModel observable

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look @ it and get back to you

Comment: I knew the containerModel(result) will overwrite the entire data, but due to my limited knowledge ( or 0) i wrote like it. Also as you can see from my json result i posted, each observables like ERPData, HomeSettings are all coming as objects independently and not under index 0 of containerModel so indexing i dont have to use.

Comment: if you are posting as model(having different entities i.e HomeSettings,Employee,erpdata) the you can fallow the same process of assigning like `self.containerModel().HomeSettings(result.HomeSettings)` no need to use index `[0]`

Comment: That's where the error is happening,as i mentioned above.HomeSettings is not a function

Comment: back to square one ha ? you can show the error in the above fiddle in can fix it for you mate . i created a exact repo of your issue and things working well .